# A question on short run equilibrium in the simple Keynesian model

Tags: macroeconomics, general-equilibrium, keynesian-economics

In the simple Keynesian model , it's generally assumed that there are no technological changes in the short run. However, as this is a macroeconomic model, changes in one or 2 industries, shouldn't have much of an impact. So how large must the change be for there to be a sizable change in the marginal propensity to spend, and thus, $b$ in the equation
$$Y=I+bY$$

where $I$ is the fixed investment.

Comment: Hi! Assumptions are something that the modeler makes, so you can always assume that $b$ is fixed, or also that it is endogenous. Which one is better for your model depends on what you are trying to do, what data you have access to, etc.

Comment: Clearly though it is impossible that both $I$ and $b$ are fixed in the above equation while $Y$ varies freely, unless $I = 0, b=1$.

Comment: @Giskard, I was just wondering when the simple linear model is not good enough of an approximation anymore, that is , how great must the change in technology be for the short run assumption to be rendered void

Comment: "*Which one is better for your model depends on what you are trying to do, what data you have access to, etc.*"

Comment: Thank you for the help.